# @InjectMocks is not injecting the the list dependency, which is a @Spy

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

**Servcice.java** (class to test)

```
class Service {
    @Autowired
    private List<Metric> dependency1;
    @Autowired
    private Executor dependency2;

}
```

**Metric.java** : interface

```
  interface Metric{
        public void fetchMetric();
    }

class Metric1 implements Metric{
        public void fetchMetric() {}
    }

class Metric2 implements Metric{
        public void fetchMetric() {}
    }
```

**ServiceTest.java** : (test class)

```
  @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    class ServiceTest {
        @Spy
        private List<Metric> dependency1;
        @Mock
        private Executor dependency2;
        
        @InjectMocks // class under test // this has above two as their dependencies.
        Service service;
    
        @Mock
        private Metric1 metric1;
        @Mock
        private Metric2 metric2;
    
        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
            // intializing the spy object list with mocks.
            this.dependency1 = Arrays.asList(metric1,
                    metric2
                   );
        }
    
        @Test
        void someTest() {
            // here in debug mode I can see that `dependency1` as a **spy**  and 'dependency1' present in the 'Service' are different, though they should be same.
        }
    }
```

Why `@InjectMock` is not able to Inject a `@Spy` List dependencies in the `Service` class object? Am I missing something here.

`dependency1` as a **spy** and `dependency1` present as a part of the `Service` are shown as two different objects on the de-bugger and making the test cases fail. I thought they should be the same.

> Should we not initialise the Spies in `@BeforeEach` method ?

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: is dependency1 autowired is actual service ?

As suggest by @Seelenvirtuose please share more details

Comment: @NakulGoyal, yes it is Autowired in Service class. Provided the complete example

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, please redo the downvote, provided the reproducible example.

Comment: Tushar , a very common refactoring pattern is to create a constructor with the 2 Autowired fields that you have with the @Autowired annotation!. This will enable you much better control in terms of setting these variables and then using them for tests.


```class Service {
 @Autowired
  public Service(List<Metric> dependency1,Executor dependency2){.....}```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` to tell mockito to instantiate your @Mocks @Spy and @InjectMocks. So after Mockito does this you change the field ServiceTest.dependency1 to be a list.

But since Mockito instantiated your CUT with the annotated dependencies, it is not updated when you change the ServiceTest.dependency1.

I would recommend to change Service to have a constructor so you can use the recommended constructor Injection.
That way you can make your test like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ServiceTest {
    
    @Mock
    private Executor dependency2;
    
    Service service;

    @Mock
    private Metric1 metric1;
    @Mock
    private Metric2 metric2;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        // intializing the spy object list with mocks.
        service = new Service(Arrays.asList(metric1,metric2), dependency2);
    }
}
```

If you want the list to be a spy, I would do something like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private Service service;

@Mock
private Executor dependency2;
@Spy
private List<Metric> dependency1;

@Test
void test() {
    // you can define what to return when there is a method call on the spy dependency1
    Metric metric1 = mock(Metric.class);
    Metric metric2 = mock(Metric.class);
    when(dependency1.get(0)).thenReturn(metric1);
    when(dependency1.get(1)).thenReturn(metric2);

    service.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: where's the spy here, I think that is the normal List object, we won't be able to capture the interactions on it, right.

Comment: what if we use ```MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)```, after the 
```this.dependency1 = Arrays.asList(metric1, metric2);```  in ```@BeforeEach``` method?

Comment: @tusharRawat updated my answer with a spy of list version

Comment: Yeah got it and we can also put all interactions with ```spies``` in ```@BeforeEach```, to write it only once I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

One way to handle it:

Remove @Spy and use @Mock on dependency1.

And you will need to handle the List w.r.t. the testcase like:

Mockito.doReturn(metric1).when(dependency1).get(ArgumentMatchers.anyString());

Comment: yeah but in that case If I have many ```metrics``` as mock, I have to write the ```doReturn``` for every mock, right. My question is more on the side why the current implementation is not working.

Comment: Because it's not capable to pre-fill the List with all metrics.
So only for mocks where it's an Autowired list, we need to handle it manually by doReturn or autoFilling the spied mock.

This implementation would work if it is Metric instead of List<Metric> or if u pre-fill before running testcases.


Hope that clarifies the answer. [It's one solution to handle]